# IE6 and IE7 Z-INDEX bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, css-position

After a few lost days, I have given up trying to solve this.
So, here is the situation and I'll be really thankful if someone could tell me what I should do:

I have a vertical menu, and the second level of the menu is absolute positioned.
The inner `<ul>` is styled `position: absolute;` and has a set `z-index`. The problem is
ie6 and ie7-specific, which does not recognize the z-index in an absolute positioned block. 
If the element was a relatively positioned, there are no problems but I need the 
element to be positioned absolute.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks a lot to everyone who's going to give their advice or opinion.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We can best answer questions when we have code samples :) If you could provide a small sample of HTML and CSS that demonstrate the issue, that would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to support IE6 and IE7? Google doesn't.

Comment: here is an example of the code:
http://jordanstd.com/Example/example.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps.

Inside absolute div, add a relative div and put your code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 and IE7 have a `z-index` [bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html) where each absolutely positioned element creates a new context for the stacking order. It's difficult to tell without seeing the html in question, but try adding `position: relative;` and `z-index: 100` (or something above the z-index of your sub-menus) to the container (parent) of all the elements with `position: absolute`.